# how to implement sliding menu and overflow menu together in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu, overflow-menu

I am new to android and want to implement sliding menu(navigation drawer) and overflow menu together in android 2.2+. How can i implement both together?

Answer (score 0):

You have some open source option for sliding menu 
For reference

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
And

https://github.com/TangKe/SlideMenu

Comment: i want to implement sliding menu with overflow menu
I can implement sliding menu alone